# The easiest most sensible way to deal with padding in a container in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, padding

I quite often build websites whose container acts as like a white page on a different coloured background and the site's content sits within that white page with a little bit of padding so that it doesn't touch the sides.

This is quite challenging when using a responsive grid. If I add say 50px of padding to the container, at certain resolutions things work perfectly but at other sizes, the page becomes too big for the screen, this is obviously to do with the widths defined in bootstrap's CSS for certain media queries.

I started going into each media query and doing some mathematics to figure out exactly how many pixels needed to be subtracted from each span and each offset in order for the page to display correctly at any given resolution but then I stopped myself and thought, there must be a better way!

I'm not averse to doing the necessary work but as I see myself coming across this problem on many if not all TB projects, I'd like to feel that I'm approaching the process in the most logical and easily-repeatable way.

Would you manually change pixel sizes for each span and offset? Or perhaps there is another more sensible way to approach a padded container?

I would much appreciate your thoughts! Thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer, but a similar framework [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) is much easier to adapt in the way you describe, IMHO. BTW, I trust you'll be using PW for the back end! :)

Comment: Absolutely Dave! Already built on PW but my maths isn't up to the challenge of these widths at the moment (63.333333333333px....). I briefly used Skeleton before TB. Would this padding be easier to accomplish with it?

Comment: Sure, the columns in Skeleton have margin-left and margin-right set at 10px, so the content never touches the edge of the container div and you can just set a background-color on <body> and you're good to go. (The site I posted in the Showcase on PW forum in June does just that.) Just need to remove background colour when it swaps to mobile layout.

Comment: Thanks Dave, good job on the site, though not sure 10px would be enough for my needs and I think increasing the padding on the container would bring about the same issues as with TB. I'm thinking I need to get involved with some SASS wizardry!

Answer (score 6):

You can set box-sizing to border-box. The problem is that the with of the 12 spans are bigger than the with of the container. You can tackle that by using *.row-fluid* which makes the grid relative.

```
.container { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 50px; }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
 http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem